# How can I get XML declaration string with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I use `lxml` to parse XML document
How can I get declaration string?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

I want to check if it is present, what encoding it has and what xml version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When parsing your document, the resulting `ElementTree` object should have a `DocInfo` object that contains information about the XML or HTML document parsed.

For XML, you may be interested in the `xml_version` and `encoding` attributes of this `DocInfo`:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
>>> tree.docinfo
<lxml.etree.DocInfo object at 0x7f8111f9ecc0>
>>> tree.docinfo.xml_version
'1.0'
>>> tree.docinfo.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just check if a string with that declaration value (  ) can be found in your XML file:

```html
    def matchLine(path, line_number, text):
        """
        path = used for defining the file to be checked
        line_number = used to identify the line that  will be checked
        text = string containing the text to match
        """
        file = open(path)
        line_file = file.readline()
        line_file = line_file.rstrip()
        line_no = 1
        while line_file != "":
            if line_no == line_number:
                if line_file == text:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            line_no = line_no+1
            line_file = file.readline()
            line_file = line_file.rstrip()
```